# add javascript file from server in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I need to add a *Javascript* file from the server to the *LocalStorage* and site header.
i try this code but some things wrong??

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = localStorage.theImage;
s.title = "myJavaScript";
$("head").append(s);

function addScript() {

    var csvRequest = new Request({
        url: "splitNumber.js",
        onSuccess: function (response) {
            var responseFile = response;
            var file = responseFile;
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var s = document.createElement("script");
                s.type = "text/javascript";
                s.src = reader.result;
                localStorage.theImage = reader.result;
                $("head").append(s);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);//attempts to read the file in question.
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `script` elements don't need and can't use a `title` attribute.

Comment: What do you want?

Comment: i have external script , i want only One time download script file to speed up site load.
`title` attribute download script file for each load page.

Comment: localstorage is not the place were you should store file and as base64 that takes up ~3x more data, put it in the indexedDB. I could recommend using [localforage](https://localforage.github.io/localForage/#data-api-setitem) is good for this.